# Python flipping x coins x times using loops but receiving odd output

Tags: python, loops, random, nested-loops, coin-flipping

I'm new to python and coding in general. I have an assignment for class to write a program that uses a loop to flip multiple coins multiple times. The code must:

1. ask for the number of coins and how many times to flip those coins.
2. Must ask again if the input is less then 0.
3. Print the result of flipping each coin the specified number of times and must be random.
4. Then print the total number of heads and tails.
   I do have to use random so suggestions of other modules or better ways to achieve randomization aren't something I'm looking for, thank you.

The output should look something like:

```
How many coins do you want to flip? 2
How many times do you want to flip each coin? 2

Coin 1
Flip: 1; Result: Heads
Flip: 2; Result: Tails

Coin 2
Flip: 1; Result: Tails
Flip: 2; Result: Heads

There were 2 Tails in total
There were 2 Heads in total
```

Here's what I tried: (I'm having to use my phone due to some irl problems to ask this so if the format is off I'm sorry!)

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0

coins = int(input("How many coins: "))

while coins !="":
    if coins \<= 0:
        print ("Invalid input")
        coins = int(input("How many coins: "))
    else:
        flips = int(input("How many times to flip: "))
        if flips \<= 0:
            print ("Invalid input")
            flips = int(input("How many times to flip: "))
        else:
            for n in range (0, coins):
                for i in range (0, flips):
                    print (" ")
                    print ("Coin %0d" %n)
                    print (" ")
                    n = coins + 1
                    for flip in range (0, flips):
                        flip = random.randint(0,1)
                        if flip == 0:
                            heads += 1
                            print ("Flips: %0d;" %i, "Result: heads")
                        else:
                            tails += 1
                            print ("Flip: %0d;" %i, "Result: tails")
                        i = flips + 1
print ("total heads:", heads)
print ("total tails:", tails)
break
```

What I get varies wildly by the numbers I input. I might flip 4 coins 3 times and it flips 6 coins. Or 1 coin 3 times and it flips 6 coins. But 1 coin 2 times flips 1 coin 2 times. The numbers counting the coins and flips also don't work right. I get results like:

```
Coin 0
Flip: 0; Result: Tails
Flip: 3; Result: Heads

Coin 2
Flip: 1; Result: Tails
Flip: 3; Result: Tails.
```

I'm stumped and at this point all the code looks like abc soup. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of `n = coins + 1`?  Or worse, `for flips in range (0, flips):`?

Comment: n = coins + 1 is supposed to tell the program to list the coins flipped. Without it the output lists as coin 0, coin 0, coin 0 instead of coin 1, coin 2, coin 3. It was supposed to say 'for flip in range (0, flips). It tells random how many numbers I need randomized in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put in the line 'for flip in range (0, flips)' not thinking that moving the 'for i in range (0, flips)' would tell the program the same thing. Which I wouldn't have figured out without Benjamin Davis or Scott Hunter and I greatly appreciate you both!
So the middle part should actually be:

```
else:
    for n in range (1, coins +1)
        print (" ")
        print ("Coin %0d" %n)
        print (" ")
        for i in range (1, flips +1)
            flip = random.randit (0,1)
            if flip == 0:
                heads += 1
                print ("Flip: %0d;" %i, "Result: heads")
            else:
                tails += 1
                print ("Flip: %0d;" %i, "Result: tails")
```

Comment: Now I can't get it to ask for new input when given a 0. I thought I had that part working.

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question to ask...

Comment: I know it's a bit late to tell you this, but I figured out the part that stopped working too. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest re-looking into your code's flow control and variable usage once you get to the evaluation stage (when you are doing the coin flipping).

Specifically, you appear to be using the number of flips for two distinct loops: `for i in range (0, flips):` and `for flips in range (0, flips):`.

Additionally, the second one (`for flips in range (0, flips):`) is overwriting the `flips` variable which you are using to store the number of flips per coin that the user requested.

Comment: It's 'for flip in range (0, flips)' its not overwriting flips. It's a seperate variable. Both the i and flips 'if' statments need to know the amount of flips I believe?

Comment: Correct, that resolves one of the issues in the code.

Comment: Now when I run your code I get `coins * flips * flips` outputs. This aligns with your for loop structure.  Looking at your lines `i = flips + 1` and `n = coins + 1` I think you might be coming from a different language where you need to specify the variable increments in a for loop (such as C or Java). Python is different, the `range(0, coins)` statement will always produce the number in order, and override any value of `n` or `i` you set inside the for loop.

Comment: I didn't know that, our teacher had used them previously so I thought they must have been necessary. I did figure out the problem though thanks to your help!